# Is it an angular ngRouter bug or am i doing something wrong

Tags: javascript, angularjs

this code is from the AngularJs [docs for ngRouter](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.3/docs/api/ngRoute.directive%3angView)

```
angular.module('ngViewExample', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate'],
  function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/Book/:bookId', {
      templateUrl: 'book.html',
      controller: BookCntl,
      controllerAs: 'book'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/Book/:bookId/ch/:chapterId', {
      templateUrl: 'chapter.html',
      controller: ChapterCntl,
      controllerAs: 'chapter'
    });

    // configure html5 to get links working on jsfiddle
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});

function MainCntl($route, $routeParams, $location) {
  this.$route = $route;
  this.$location = $location;
  this.$routeParams = $routeParams;
}

function BookCntl($routeParams) {
  this.name = "BookCntl";
  this.params = $routeParams;
}

function ChapterCntl($routeParams) {
  this.name = "ChapterCntl";
  this.params = $routeParams;
}
```

### lets concentrate on the elements where the error appears:

#### The BookCtrl:

```
function BookCntl($routeParams) {
  this.name = "BookCntl";
  this.params = $routeParams;
}
```

#### The ChapterCtrl:

```
function ChapterCntl($routeParams) {
  this.name = "ChapterCntl";
  this.params = $routeParams;
}
```

#### The router function

```
  function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/Book/:bookId', {
      templateUrl: 'book.html',
      controller: BookCntl,
      controllerAs: 'book'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/Book/:bookId/ch/:chapterId', {
      templateUrl: 'chapter.html',
      controller: ChapterCntl,
      controllerAs: 'chapter'
    });
    // configure html5 to get links working on jsfiddle
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

Now this if you do edit on plunker will work correctly.
But if we declare the BookCtrl and the ChapterCtrl differently like this:

```
angular.module('ngViewExample', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate'],
  function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/Book/:bookId', {
      templateUrl: 'book.html',
      controller: BookCntl,
      controllerAs: 'book'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/Book/:bookId/ch/:chapterId', {
      templateUrl: 'chapter.html',
      controller: ChapterCntl,
      controllerAs: 'chapter'
    });

    // configure html5 to get links working on jsfiddle
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}).controller('MainCntl', function($route, $routeParams, $location) {
  this.$route = $route;
  this.$location = $location;
  this.$routeParams = $routeParams;
}).controller('BookCntl', function($routeParams) {
  this.name = "BookCntl";
  this.params = $routeParams;
}).controller('ChapterCntl', function($routeParams) {
  this.name = "ChapterCntl";
  this.params = $routeParams;
});
```

The main ngViewExample module is no longer defined because it can't find the BookCtrl, leading to this error:

> Failed to instantiate module ngViewExample due to:
>   ReferenceError: BookCntl is not defined
>       at http://run.plnkr.co/WS5cdGZ2VT2oHDLR/script.js:5:19
>       at Object.d [as invoke] (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.3/angular.min.js:30:232)
>       at http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.3/angular.min.js:29:58
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at q (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.3/angular.min.js:7:255)
>       at e (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.3/angular.min.js:28:374)
>       at Yb (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.3/angular.min.js:32:427)
>       at Xb.c (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.3/angular.min.js:17:315)
>       at Xb (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.3/angular.min.js:18:30)
>       at Rc (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.3/angular.min.js:17:99

So basically the ngViewExample is not instantiated because BookCntl is not defined.
How to tell the router function to look for the BookCntl in the controllers of the module?
Or should I report this as a bug in the angular site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use quotes on the controller names in the $routeProvider definition if you declare them like that.

```
angular.module('ngViewExample', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate'],
  function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/Book/:bookId', {
      templateUrl: 'book.html',
      controller: 'BookCntl',
      controllerAs: 'book'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/Book/:bookId/ch/:chapterId', {
      templateUrl: 'chapter.html',
      controller: 'ChapterCntl',
      controllerAs: 'chapter'
    });

    // configure html5 to get links working on jsfiddle
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}).controller('MainCntl', function($route, $routeParams, $location) {
  this.$route = $route;
  this.$location = $location;
  this.$routeParams = $routeParams;
}).controller('BookCntl', function($routeParams) {
  this.name = "BookCntl";
  this.params = $routeParams;
}).controller('ChapterCntl', function($routeParams) {
  this.name = "ChapterCntl";
  this.params = $routeParams;
});
```

This should work.